# How to POST data with M2M?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to write an API endpoint that creates data for 2 models, linked together by a many-to-many relationship. Let's say these models are `User` and `Group`.

Requirements:

- Both involved models does not exist yet, so I can not use `pk` to describe them.
- The endpoint can create as many users/groups as I want.

If the relation between those models would have been a 1->N (ie. a user can be in N groups, but a group can be related to 1 user), the solution would have been trivial:

```
'user1': {'name': "robert",
         'groups': [{'name': 'group1'}, {'name': 'group2'}]
         }
'user2': {'name': "jean",
         'groups': [{'name': 'group3'}, {'name': 'group4'}]
         }
```

But as it's a M2M, how I am supposed to do this? Nesting does not work:

```
'user1': {'name': "robert",
         'groups': [{'name': 'group1'}, {'name': 'group2'}]
         }
'user2': {'name': "jean",
         'groups': [{'name': 'group2'}, {'name': 'group3'}]
         }
```

In this case, the server will probably try to create 4 groups instead of 3. Plus, I'm repeting myself trying to specify 1 object twice.

*Note that here, a group object is a simple model, but in my real case, the object is a complex one with multi-level nesting one, so I can not repeat myself.*

How would you solve this?
The only solution I have in mind, is to make two HTTP calls instead of one.

NOTE: I'm using Django and Django Rest Framework.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, assuming you have `groups = ManyToManyField(Group)` in your user model.

Define the field `groups = GroupSerializer()` in your user serializer (you must implement `GroupSerializer` as a `ModelSerializer`).

In your serializer's `create` method, you will have something like this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    // Groups list has existing groups and new ones as well
    groups = validated_data.pop('groups')

    // Get existing groups by name
    existing_groups = Group.objects.filter(name__in=[g.name for g in groups])
    existing_group_names = [g.name for g in existing_groups]

    // Create new groups
    groups_to_create = []
    for g in groups:
        if g.name not in existing_group_names:
            groups_to_create.append(g)
    Group.objects.bulk_create(groups_to_create)

    // Now that we have all groups, create the user and add the groups to his groups list, updating the M2M relationship
    user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
    user.groups.add(existing_groups + groups_to_create)
```

Comment: Thanks, but in no way, group name must be unique. I chose this example because it seemed easy, but in my case, we can NOT identify objects by their name, we need pks.